# Issue with chart.RiskReturnScatter in performance analytics, need finite 'ylim' values error

Tags: programming, performanceanalytics

I am currently trying to create a Risk Return Scatter plot using the following code

```
chart.RiskReturnScatter(performance[x:y, portfolio.list], Rf = rf, main = "", cex.axis = 1.5, cex.lab = 1.5)
```

the performance[x:y, portfolio.list] dataframe is formatted as:

```
             HR Muni Bond HR Taxable Bond Composite Portfolio
2017-12-31           NA          -0.006       -0.0025071641
2018-03-31           NA          -0.003       -0.0012671892
2018-06-30           NA           0.007        0.0028773074
2018-09-30           NA          -0.001       -0.0004108567
```

I modified my code to replace the NA's with zeros thinking that this would correct the error:

```
chart.RiskReturnScatter(performance[x:y, portfolio.list][is.na(performance[x:y, portfolio.list])]<-0,Rf=rf,main="", cex.axis = 1.5, cex.lab = 1.5)
```

Nope, that didn't fix the issue. I received the following error: "Error in checkData(R): The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'."

I went back to the drawing board and added tk_xts to coerce the dataframe back to the xts format using this code:

```
chart.RiskReturnScatter(tk_xts(performance[x:y, portfolio.list][is.na(performance[x:y, portfolio.list])]<-0, by 1),Rf=rf,main="", cex.axis = 1.5, cex.lab = 1.5)
```

I think I am up to strike 3. I now get this error: "Error in xts::xts(data, ...) : order.by requires an appropriate time-based object"

I am not sure where to proceed next. Basically, what is the best way to handle NA's in PerformanceAnalytics? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure your index is a proper date object with as.Date() and see if that fixes the issue. Usually "order.by requires an appropriate time-based object" means that the index isn't the right kind of date object that xts expects to receive.